# How to test all implementations of an interface have executed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5

I have a question related to testing of dependency injection in a spring boot application.
I have an interface like

```
Interface I {void doSomething()}
@Component
class I1 {void someSomething(){//som impl}}
@Component
class I2 {void someSomething(){//som impl}}
@Component
class I2 {void someSomething(){//som impl}}

@Service
class SomeService {
@Autowired
private List<I> rules;

void someMethod() {
rules.forEach(//do something);
  }
}
```

I want to write a Unit test for service class and want to see what all implementations of `Interface I` that have run. Is there a way of knowing this ? The reason is once a developer forgot to annotate an implementation of `Interface I` as a spring component and the implementation never ran as it was not injected. So can we verify this somehow in tests that what all implementations have run. How can we write such test?

Comment: There are coverage tools which you can run with your unit tests/CI and will tell you when newly added code is not 100% covered by your tests.

Comment: But here you are testing whether your container has instantiated all the components you expect, which is not going to be verified by unit tests. I'd suggest that you should add a functional test which relies on that component existing to pass.

Comment: You could write test using `archunit` or smt similar enforcing that classes implementing interface have `@Component` annotation